# pyodbc error schema does not exist or you do not have permission

Tags: python, sql-server, database, pyodbc

My code:

```
con = pyodbc.connect("DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=WIN-RCNSTVE00SV\SQLEXPRESS;UID=sa;PWD=password;database=master",autocommit=True)
cursor = con.cursor()

cursor.execute("create database test_db")
cursor.execute("create table test_db.tb(id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, random_txt VARCHAR(50), sequence TEXT, status BIT)")
```

After creating the database, I'm not able to create a table in it. I get this error:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]The specified schema name "test_db" either does not exist or you do not have permission to use it. (2760)
```

I tried executing the grant permission query after the create database but  got the same error. I also tried creating a new con(connection) specifying the database but didn't work. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `schema` name. It should be

```sql
create table test_db.dbo.tb
(                  --^^^ Missing schema name 
id INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, 
random_txt VARCHAR(50), 
sequence TEXT, 
status BIT
)
```

A fully qualified object name will be in this format

> DatabaseName.SchemaName.ObjectName

If you have any other schema created and you want to create the new table in that schema then replace the `schema name` with `dbo`. By default the objects will be created in `dbo` schema. If you want to create the table in `dbo` schema then you can write like this as well

```sql
Create table test_db..tb()
```

`..` implicitly points to the `dbo` schema